# Should I add and delete index in one page?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

Let's say I have `players` table. It consists with 3 rows(it has much more, but let's suppose it has only 3). `member_id, name, exp`. I use `member_id` row in every page so that's why I added index only to `member_id`. But I want to make a top players' list in one page with the highest `exp`. So I do something like that:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY `exp` DESC");
```

If I have 10k players, I can't run query like this without adding index to `exp`. So my question is, should I do like this:

```
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `players` ADD INDEX ( `exp` )");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY `exp` DESC");
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `players` DROP INDEX `exp`");
```

Or there is something else better I can do? Because adding and removing indexes is quite expensive. But probably I could do cache every 10 minutes for example.

Comment: What's your reason for not wanting a permanent index on `exp`? (BTW, it would make *me* nervous if my website was using db credentials that give it permission to alter the schema.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely not.

Building an index takes more time than scanning the entire table, so you will severely degrade your performance.

Just build the index once and leave it.

Comment: But if I would cache it and run this query only every 10 minutes? Would it be so bad? Because adding to much indexes will make my `UPDATE` queries slower, I guess.

Comment: @hey: Are you writing to the `players` table hundreds of times per second? Don't let an unfounded concern about update performance drive you to contort your entire application.

Comment: Ok. <span style="color: #fff"></span>

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY `exp` DESC
```

This requires reading the whole table and sorting it.

```
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `players` ADD INDEX ( `exp` )");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY `exp` DESC");
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `players` DROP INDEX `exp`");
```

This requires reading the whole table, sorting it, writing the results of the sort to the disk, reading them back from the disk, then removing them: all that having the table locked.

The first option is much faster and better for concurrency.

It will be yet faster if you create a permanent index.

`10k` records is far too few to worry about `DML` performance.

Answer (score 0):

### With "one time" index

```
O(n*log(n)) + O(n) + [cost of index delete - don't know this]
```

### With index generated

`O(n)` - in ordering, but you have `O(log(N))` additional time while `INSERT` and `UPDATE exp column`

---

`O(n)` is much faster than `O(n*log(n)) + O(n)` then you generate index and leave this, but if you have **MUCH MORE** changes on `exp` than `ORDER by exp` you need then think about don't indexing this column because it was in overall longer. Or use other solution like `SELECT` ordered by `exp` caching?

Propably caching result of `SELECT` is the **best solution for this problem**, but do this select without `ADDING` and `DROPING INDEX` because this don't have any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Artefacto is right, and worse, altering a table is a blocking procedure, meaning that all your selects and updates are going to pile up while that's going on. If you have any sort of load on your database, this will destroy it. Either use the index or don't, but don't build and destroy it.